# When changing ISPs, do I have to order a new static IP address?

Tags: ip-address

With my current ISP, I have a static IP address for the server to be able to access it from anywhere in the world. Now I'm changing ISPs - should I ask a new ISP for new static IP address, or can I reuse the current one?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

You will not be able to reuse the current one, it will be part of your current ISP address range, and will not be portable to your new ISP

Comment: I actually made a mistake in terminology I think. I meant external IP address, which is also a static one, but just to clarify. Does your comment still stand with this clarification?

Comment: Yes the comment still applies, unless you are an organisation that has PI (Provider Independent) address space, then the addresses cannot be carried from one ISP to another.  This is fundamental to practical Internet routing.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have your own provider-independent block of addresses, you will not be able to take your addresses with you.

ISP will not advertise prefixes longer than `/24` for IPv4 or `/48` for IPv6. That means if your block of addresses is smaller than those, the IP addresses are assigned to the ISP, not to you. A new ISP cannot advertise your address block if it belongs to your former ISP.